# Input Range in 1D array

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing some code to put a range into an array so i can create plots by analyzing the data inside that array. I am trying to use a general code for the range since the input can be different depending on the type of analysis i want to perform. Tried to find a solution for this in other questions without success.

```
Dim DieBankArray As Variant

last_row = Sheets("Tabela CT geral").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row 'Last row of the data set
For i = 0 To last_row - 2                                       '-2 to exclude the first line and another value because the array first position is 0, not 1
    DieBankArray(i) = Range("A" & i + 2)
Next
```

The return is a type mismatch error that i can't understand...

Comment: You need to `ReDim` before you attempt to read values into the array.

Comment: You can do this without a loop.

Comment: Actually my objective was to write values into the array and from what i saw i can use it as variant to insert values into it. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: I always recommend [this article](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) for dealing with arrays and ranges. You can read a range into a variant array in one step, but that is a 2D array.

Comment: Change the order in your code. Put the dim after you know the number of items you need to get and dim the array to that size

Comment: You can use Evaluate to get the values into a 1D array in one step if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
Function RangeTo1DArray(rngStart As Range)
    Dim rv(), arr, r As Long, n As Long
    'read the source data to an array for better performance
    With rngStart.Parent
        arr = .Range(rngStart, .Cells(Rows.Count, rngStart.Column).End(xlUp)).Value
    End With
    n = UBound(arr, 1)
    ReDim rv(0 To n - 1)
    'Fill the output array.  Note: purposefully not using transpose()
    '   to avoid its limitations
    For r = 1 To n
        rv(r - 1) = arr(r, 1)
    Next r

    RangeTo1DArray= rv
End Function
```

Comment: I like the function aproach, still need to go deep on this function topic. Thanks for the help Tim!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i used the Redim and it worked just fine.

What i couldn't understand is that there's a need to set the correct size of an array to read/write data. I thought a simple Dim as Variant should be enough to store the data at my will without need to set a correct size each time i want to use an array.

The code after ReDim:

```
Dim DieBankArray As Variant
last_row = Sheets("Tabela CT geral").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row 'Last row of the data set
ReDim DieBankArray(A2 To last_row - 2)

    For i = 0 To last_row - 2                                       '-2 to exclude the first line and another value because the array first position is 0, not 1
        DieBankArray(i) = Range("A" & i + 2)
    Next
```

Comment: "I thought a simple Dim as Variant should be enough to store the data at my will without need to set a correct size each time i want to use an array." - that's not how arrays work. For more reading, see [Using Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-arrays). If you don't want to worry about sizing, use a Collection.

Comment: Still learning by myself, sometimes it's not easy to understand some limitations. Thanks for the help and for the article

Comment: No problem! I'm sure you're making great progress. No worries, we were all there at one point. Happy coding!